# Provide full file path inside a JSON

Tags: json, powershell

I want to use JSON file to store parameters for my powershell script. Few of the JSON attributes have Complete file paths as values.

The https://jsonlint.com/ shows that the JSON is valid. However, `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet throws and error.

[image]

Please help me to fix this JSON parsing.

JSON:

```
    {
  "region": "US",
  "proxy_address_exception_list": "1.1.1.1; 2.2.2.2",
  "dsvm_ip_address": "10.1.1.1",
  "svm_ip_address": "10.2.2.2",
  "url_without_xto": "abc.com",
  "url_with_xto": "def-xto.com",
  "web_server_farm_name": "dss",
  "full_path_to_requestrouter_amd64_msi": "c:\\script_downloads\\requestrouter.msi",
  "full_path_to_rewrite_amd64_en_US_msi": "c:\\script_downloads\\rewrite.msi",
  "full_path_to_webfarm_v1_1_amd64_en_US_msi" : "c:\\script_downloads\\webfarm.msi",
  "full_path_to_application_host_config": "c:\\script_downloads\\applicationHost.config"
}
```

PowerShell code:

```
# Get parameter_list from file 
$parameter_list_json = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\manjug\Desktop\Visualization_Automation\parameters.json" -Raw
$parameter_list = ConvertFrom-Json $parameter_list_json
```

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\manjug\Desktop> # Get parameter_list from file 
$parameter_list_json = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\manjug\Desktop\Visualization_Automation\parameters.json" -Raw
$parameter_list = ConvertFrom-Json $parameter_list_json
ConvertFrom-Json : Unrecognized escape sequence. (293): {
  "region": "US",
  "proxy_address_exception_list": "1.1.1.1; 2.2.2.2",
  "dsvm_ip_address": "10.1.1.1.",
  "svm_ip_address": "10.2.2.2",
  "url_without_xto": "abc.com",
  "url_with_xto": "def-xto.com",
  "web_server_farm_name": "dss",
  "full_path_to_requestrouter_amd64_msi": "c:\script_downloads\requestrouter_amd64_msi",
  "full_path_to_rewrite_amd64_en_US_msi": "c:\script_downloads\rewrite_amd64_en_US_msi",
  "full_path_to_webfarm_v1_1_amd64_en_US_msi" : "c:\script_downloads\webfarm_v1_1_amd64_en_US_msi",
  "full_path_to_application_host_config": "c:\script_downloads\applicationHost.config"
}
At line:3 char:19
+ $parameter_list = ConvertFrom-Json $parameter_list_json
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an escape in that string:

```
"full_path_to_requestrouter_amd64_msi": "c:\script_downloads\\requestrouter.msi",
```

Just after `c:`. This should be `c:\\script`.
Once you fix this, this works:

```
$json = @"
{
  "region": "US",
  "proxy_address_exception_list": "1.1.1.1; 2.2.2.2",
  "dsvm_ip_address": "10.1.1.1",
  "svm_ip_address": "10.2.2.2",
  "url_without_xto": "abc.com",
  "url_with_xto": "def-xto.com",
  "web_server_farm_name": "dss",
  "full_path_to_requestrouter_amd64_msi": "c:\\script_downloads\\requestrouter.msi",
  "full_path_to_rewrite_amd64_en_US_msi": "c:\\script_downloads\\rewrite.msi",
  "full_path_to_webfarm_v1_1_amd64_en_US_msi" : "c:\\script_downloads\\webfarm.msi",
  "full_path_to_application_host_config": "c:\\script_downloads\\applicationHost.config"
}
"@

$x = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

$x

region                                    : US
proxy_address_exception_list              : 1.1.1.1; 2.2.2.2
dsvm_ip_address                           : 10.1.1.1
svm_ip_address                            : 10.2.2.2
url_without_xto                           : abc.com
url_with_xto                              : def-xto.com
web_server_farm_name                      : dss
full_path_to_requestrouter_amd64_msi      : c:\script_downloads\requestrouter.msi
full_path_to_rewrite_amd64_en_US_msi      : c:\script_downloads\rewrite.msi
full_path_to_webfarm_v1_1_amd64_en_US_msi : c:\script_downloads\webfarm.msi
full_path_to_application_host_config      : c:\script_downloads\applicationHost.config
```